# How to implement multiple test sets running with multiple test contexts?

Tags: java, junit4, parameterized

I'm currently working on jUnit4 testing and I have a test context, let's say particular.
I have to achieve multiple test sets in different contexts. So, the solution I tried is a mix of jUnit4 Suite and jUnit4 Parameterized tests.

To answer main questions :

- I have multiple context because the app can run by different modes (let's just say "Centralized" and "Distributed") and I have to play each test in each mode. Whatever the mode, the test should be OK.
- I would like to implement separated test sets because I have to write a lot of tests and, to be as clean as possible, I would group them by "type" (app API tests, app features tests, app IHM tests, ...)
- The app needs multiple docker container to run. There is a huge config to set up to run tests.

This is what I have done :

**Test suite definition :**

```java
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({FirstTestSet.class, SecondTestSet.class})
public abstract class AllMyTests {}
```

```java
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public abstract class TestSet {
    @Parameter
    public ITestContext context;

    @Parameters(name = "Test with context : {0}")
    public static Collection<ITestContext> TestContexts() {
        return Arrays.asList(new ContextA(), new ContextB());
    }

    @ClassRule
    public static RuleChain chainTestSet = RuleChain.outerRule(new LoggingRule("First Rule"))
        .around(new LoggingRule("Second Rule"))
        .around(new LoggingRule("Third Rule"));

    @BeforeClass
    public static void BeforeClass() { System.out.println("------ BeforeClass"); }
    @Rule
    public TestRule Rule() { return new LoggingRule("Intermediate Rule"); }
    @Before
    public void Before() { System.out.println("------ Before"); }
    @After
    public void After() { System.out.println("------ After"); }
    @AfterClass
    public static void AfterClass() { System.out.println("------ AfterClass"); }
}
```

```java
public class FirstTestSet extends TestSet {
    @Test
    public void myTestOne() { System.out.println("--- Hello ! FirstTestSet.myTestOne from " + context.getName()); }
}
```

```java
public class SecondTestSet extends TestSet {
    @Test
    public void myTestTwo() { System.out.println("--- Hello again ! SecondTestSet.myTestTwo from " + context.getName()); }
}
```

**Test contexts definition :**

```java
public interface ITestContext { String getName(); }
```

```java
public class ContextA implements ITestContext {
    public String getName() { return this.getClass().getName() + " (Centralised context)"; }

    @ClassRule
    public static RuleChain chainContextA = RuleChain.outerRule(new LoggingRule("Run outer container"))
        .around(new LoggingRule("Run container context A"))
        .around(new LoggingRule("Run outer container"));
}
```

*I will talk about `chainContextA` at the end*

```java
public class ContextB implements ITestContext {
    public String getName() { return this.getClass().getName() + " (Distributed context)"; }

    @ClassRule
    public static RuleChain chainContextB = RuleChain.outerRule(new LoggingRule("Run outer container"))
        .around(new LoggingRule("Run container context B - 1"))
        .around(new LoggingRule("Run container context B - 2"))
        .around(new LoggingRule("Run inner container"));
}
```

*I will talk about `chainContextB` at the end*

**LoggingRule definition :**

```java
public class LoggingRule implements TestRule {
    private String message;
    public LoggingRule(String message) { this.message = message; }

    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                try {
                    System.out.println("------ Begin Rule : " + message));
                    base.evaluate();
                } finally {
                    System.out.println("------ End Rule : " + message));
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

With all of this, when I run "AllMyTests", this is the output :

```
------ Begin Rule : Intermediate Rule
------ Before
--- Hello ! FirstTestSet.myTestOne from test.ContextA (Centralised context)
------ After
------ End Rule : Intermediate Rule
------ Begin Rule : Intermediate Rule
------ Before
--- Hello ! FirstTestSet.myTestOne from test.ContextB (Distributed context)
------ After
------ End Rule : Intermediate Rule
------ AfterClass
------ End Rule : Third Rule
------ End Rule : Second Rule
------ End Rule : First Rule
------ Begin Rule : First Rule
------ Begin Rule : Second Rule
------ Begin Rule : Third Rule
------ BeforeClass
------ Begin Rule : Intermediate Rule
------ Before
--- Hello again ! SecondTestSet.myTestTwo from test.ContextA (Centralised context)
------ After
------ End Rule : Intermediate Rule
------ Begin Rule : Intermediate Rule
------ Before
--- Hello again ! SecondTestSet.myTestTwo from test.ContextB (Distributed context)
------ After
------ End Rule : Intermediate Rule
------ AfterClass
------ End Rule : Third Rule
------ End Rule : Second Rule
------ End Rule : First Rule
------ Begin Rule : First Rule
------ Begin Rule : Second Rule
------ Begin Rule : Third Rule
------ BeforeClass
```

Looks nearly OK, the @ClassRule used is `chainTestSet`, all the tests run, have a context and run with each context, but the @ClassRule and the @BeforeClass are not working as they should. The problem is obvious if I run only one test :

```
------ Begin Rule : Intermediate Rule
------ Before
--- Hello ! FirstTestSet.myTestOne from test.ContextA (Centralised context)
------ After
------ End Rule : Intermediate Rule
------ Begin Rule : Intermediate Rule
------ Before
--- Hello ! FirstTestSet.myTestOne from test.ContextB (Distributed context)
------ After
------ End Rule : Intermediate Rule
------ AfterClass
------ End Rule : Third Rule
------ End Rule : Second Rule
------ End Rule : First Rule
------ Begin Rule : First Rule
------ Begin Rule : Second Rule
------ Begin Rule : Third Rule
------ BeforeClass
```

**So, can someone explain me why the "Begin" part of the @ClassRule is executed after the "End" part ? And why the @BeforeClass at the end ?**

**Moreover, if anyone have a better idea of how to implement this type of test process, I would be happy to ear about it :)**

## `chainContextA` and `chainContextB`

As you can see in this exemple, the @ClassRule that is used is `chainTestSet` defined in `TestSet` and `chainContextA` and `chainContextB` are not.
I told I have a Centralised and a Distributed mode so the docker environnement I would like to use in each is different.

**How can I "bind" a @ClassRule to the context (that is a parameter of a test set ! :D) to use the correct environnement in each mode ?**

I understand that this can look a really strange test implementation but this is what I tried, maybe someone have a lot more beautiful way to implement this ??

Thank for reading, I will appreciate any help ;)

Comment: Is it mandantory to use JUnit4? Because JUnit5 have the 'parameterized' feature. https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5

Comment: @Mafick Yes, I have to use jUnit4. The class TestSet is a parameterized class in the exemple above, I don't know if there is a lot of changes between jUnit 4 and 5 talking about parameterized feature but anyway, I can't change :)